# How to create clickable chart in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mschart

How to create a chart that allows the user to click on the specific chart area,
when user click on the specific chart are I want to fire some event on that,
like I want to display more detailed chart on the item user have clicked.

I have used **Webchart, MicrosoftChart** but both provides chart as image so no clickable area there any alternate?

Comment: you can check fusion charts. it provides the functionality you are looking for. Here is the link http://www.fusioncharts.com

Comment: I have tried to work with fusioncharts, but what I find the difficulty is it requires height(Barchart) parameter and I don't know how to bind datatable to the chart, any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The microsoft chart control definitely does support click-through. Check [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150803/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102809-1.aspx) article out at 4guysfromrolla.

Comment: Thanks, found the concern code, have a query on chart, I want to display 60 students marks in chart for particular exam, when I`m using bar chart Its getting extra large in width so disturbs the design of page, second when I`m using Pie chart the students name(Legend) are being so congested that its impossible to identity so, what should I now do?

Comment: @Darshan Joshi - It sounds like you need to adjust how you are drawing the map.